# Android string encoding and html entities converting

Tags: android, html, encoding, entities

There is a String in Android Java. How do I change it to another given encoding and replace HTML-entities such as `&amp;` with `&`?

This is so that international symbols can be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

to **decode Html String** you can use `Html.fromHtml()`

like

```
Html.fromHtml((String) htmlCode).toString();
```

if you want **reverse**

than you can use `TextUtils.htmlEncode()`

Comment: Thanks. Replacing HTML entities works. About encoding yet have no tries.

Comment: this is not working any more, in googles documentations it is noted that this method is deprecated in API level 24.

Comment: Docs also state to use `fromHtml(String source, int flags)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add denpendency:

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.3'
```

And use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(s)`, then get the result.