# HTML encoding escaping problems

Tags: html, encoding, escaping

I'm doing an Android app in which I make a query to a webservice, get a JsonObject and after getting the desired String I find strings like: **est&amp;aacute;**

I've tried this two:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML4(text);
```

With the result of transforming **&amp;aacute** into **&amp;amp;aacute**

```
Html.escapeHtml(test));
```

Which does nothing.

Any ideas how too  transform this into `á` or the corresponding character?

Comment: It looks like your string contains actual HTML.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to display it properly in a TextView. Now it doesn't display á.

Comment: @Calefaccion, i f you want to have as result "est&á" the initial string must be "est&amp;&aacute;"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stated you had used the following:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHTML4(text);
```

**Instead** try this:

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML4(text);
```

You were re-encoding the HTML entitites;

Documentation here:

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

```
// import commons http://commons.apache.org
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public static String stripHtml(String str) {
 return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(str.replaceAll("<[A-Za-z/].*?>", "")).trim();
}
```

In addition, you can use this to decode other encoded types (**JSON**, XML, etc) or use it to encode.

---

This isn't what you asked but may also be useful for URL decoding:

```
String result = URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

API reference here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html

Comment: URL encoding != HTML entities.

Comment: I'm pretty new with all these stuff of encoding. Thanks for the help i really was getting mad with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Will be enough with:

```
String myInitialtext = "est&amp;&aacute;";  
Spanned mysString = Html.fromHtml(myInitialtext);
String result = mysString.toString();
```

now `result` has the value of `est&á`

Here is a similar question:

[Android string encoding and html entities converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643512/android-string-encoding-and-html-entities-converting)